# NLTK WordNetLemmatizer: Not Lemmatizing as Expected

Tags: python, nltk

I'm trying to lemmatize all of the words in a sentence with NLTK's WordNetLemmatizer.  I have a bunch of sentences but am just using the first sentence to ensure I'm doing this correctly.  Here's what I have:

```
train_sentences[0]

"Explanation Why edits made username Hardcore Metallica Fan reverted? They vandalisms, closure GAs I voted New York Dolls FAC. And please remove template talk page since I'm retired now.89.205.38.27"
```

So now I try to lemmatize each word as follows:

```
lemmatizer = WordNetLemmatizer()
new_sent = [lemmatizer.lemmatize(word) for word in train_sentences[0].split()]
print(new_sent)
```

And I get back:

```
['Explanation', 'Why', 'edits', 'made', 'username', 'Hardcore', 'Metallica', 'Fan', 'reverted?', 'They', 'vandalisms,', 'closure', 'GAs', 'I', 'voted', 'New', 'York', 'Dolls', 'FAC.', 'And', 'please', 'remove', 'template', 'talk', 'page', 'since', "I'm", 'retired', 'now.89.205.38.27']
```

A couple questions:

1) Why does "edits" not get transformed into "edit"?  Admittedly, if I do `lemmatizer.lemmatize("edits")` I get back `edits` but was surprised.

2) Why is "vandalisms" not transformed into "vandalism"?  This one is very surprising, since if I do `lemmatizer.lemmatize("vandalisms")`, I get back `vandalism`...

Any clarification / guidance would be awesome!

Comment: Possible duplicate of [this SO answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25534214/nltk-wordnet-lemmatizer-shouldnt-it-lemmatize-all-inflections-of-a-word).

Comment: Dupe of https://stackoverflow.com/a/49356358/610569

Answer (score 4, accepted):

## TL;DR

First tag the sentence, then use the POS tag as the additional parameter input for the lemmatization.

```
from nltk import pos_tag
from nltk.stem import WordNetLemmatizer

wnl = WordNetLemmatizer()

def penn2morphy(penntag):
    """ Converts Penn Treebank tags to WordNet. """
    morphy_tag = {'NN':'n', 'JJ':'a',
                  'VB':'v', 'RB':'r'}
    try:
        return morphy_tag[penntag[:2]]
    except:
        return 'n' 

def lemmatize_sent(text): 
    # Text input is string, returns lowercased strings.
    return [wnl.lemmatize(word.lower(), pos=penn2morphy(tag)) 
            for word, tag in pos_tag(word_tokenize(text))]

lemmatize_sent('He is walking to school')
```

For a detailed walkthrough of how and why the POS tag is necessary see https://www.kaggle.com/alvations/basic-nlp-with-nltk

---

Alternatively, you can use `pywsd` tokenizer + lemmatizer, a wrapper of NLTK's `WordNetLemmatizer`:

Install:

```
pip install -U nltk
python -m nltk.downloader popular
pip install -U pywsd
```

Code:

```
>>> from pywsd.utils import lemmatize_sentence
Warming up PyWSD (takes ~10 secs)... took 9.307677984237671 secs.

>>> text = "Mary leaves the room"
>>> lemmatize_sentence(text)
['mary', 'leave', 'the', 'room']

>>> text = 'Dew drops fall from the leaves'
>>> lemmatize_sentence(text)
['dew', 'drop', 'fall', 'from', 'the', 'leaf']
```

---

(Note to moderators: I can't mark this question as duplicate of [nltk: How to lemmatize taking surrounding words into context?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49354691/nltk-how-to-lemmatize-taking-surrounding-words-into-context) because the answer wasn't accepted there but it is a duplicate).

Answer (score 1):

1. This is really something that the [`nltk` community](https://github.com/nltk/nltk/issues) would be able to answer.
2. This is happening because of the `,` at the end of `vandalisms,`.To remove this trailing `,`,  you could use `.strip(',')` or use mutliple delimiters [as described here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4998629/python-split-string-with-multiple-delimiters).

Comment: Personally, I try to avoid using the repo issue for questions though there are many there. Github should really just host a different feature to separate real code/doc/test issues from questions.

Comment: @alvas I agree. But then I knew know other place where this could be asked. Wasn't aware of the issue really(just saw your answer). I thought it was a bug/intential features in NLTK's internal workings