# Why doesn't stemming\ lemmatization in nltk perform accurately on pandas dataframe?

Tags: python, dataframe, nltk, stemming, lemmatization

I am trying to implement stemming and lemmatization from nltk package on a Pandas dataframe. I wrote the following function but somewhere it is not performing the stemming and lemmatization. Please let me know the changes required to be made.

```
from nltk.tokenize import RegexpTokenizer
from nltk.stem.wordnet import WordNetLemmatizer
from nltk.stem import LancasterStemmer

stemmer=LancasterStemmer()
lemmer=WordNetLemmatizer()

alpha_tokenizer=RegexpTokenizer('[A-Za-z]\w+')
def process_sentence(words):
    words=words.lower()
    tokens=alpha_tokenizer.tokenize(words)
    for index,word in enumerate(tokens):
        tokens[index]=stemmer.stem(word)
        tokens[index]=lemmer.lemmatize(word,'v')
        tokens[index]=lemmer.lemmatize(word,'n')

    return tokens

print([process_sentence(item) for item in ['abaci', 'happy dogs']])

# [['abacus'], ['happy', 'dog']]
```

Comment: " I wrote the following function but somewhere it is not performing the work it is intended to so." What, exactly isn't working?

Comment: Thanks for pointing out. It is not performing stemming and lemmatization. Also, I will make the edit.

Comment: i've edited your question to make it runnable, and it seems to be working OK for me ... what is your desired output?

Comment: Words like 'working', 'worked', 'updated' are not getting to lemma.

Comment: Have you tried https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49354691/nltk-how-to-lemmatize-taking-surrounding-words-into-context ?